# Speeding Up Datafile Reading Program For School Project

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, filter

I am in a lower-level coding class (Python) and have a major project due in three days. One of our grading criteria is program speed. My program runs in about 30 seconds, ideally it would execute in 15 or less. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
import time

start_time = time.time()#for printing execution time

#function for appending any number of files to a dataframe

def read_data_files(pre, start, end): #reading in the data
    data = pd.DataFrame()#dataframe with all the data from files
    x = start

    while x <= end:
        filename = pre + str(x) + ".csv" #string manipulation
        dpath = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\jacks\\Downloads\\BMEN 207 Project 1 
        Data\\" + filename )

        for y in dpath:
            dpath = dpath.rename(columns = {y: y})
    
        data = data.append(dpath)
        x += 1
       
    return data

data = read_data_files("Data_", 5, 163) #start, end, prefix...

#converting to human time and adding to new column in dataframe
human_time = []

for i in data[' Time']:
    i = int(i)
    j = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(i).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    human_time.append(j)

human_timen = np.array(human_time) #had issues here for some reason, so i 
created another array to replace the time column in the dataframe
data[' Time'] = human_timen

hours = [] #for use as x-axis in plot
stdlist = [] #for use as y-axis in plot
histlist = [] #for storing magnitudes of most active hour

def magfind(row): #separate function to calculate the magnitude of each row in 
each dataframe
    return (row[' Acc X'] ** 2 + row[' Acc Y'] ** 2 + row[' Acc Z'] ** 2) ** .5

def filterfunction(intro1, intro2, first, last): #two different intros to deal 
with the issue of '00:' versus '10:' timestamps
    k = first
    meanmax = 0 
    active = 0

    while k <= last:
        if 0 <= k < 7: #data from hours 0 to 6, none after
            hr = intro1 + str(k) + ':'
            tfilter = data[' Time'].str.contains(hr)
            acc = data.loc[tfilter, [' Acc X', ' Acc Y', ' Acc Z']]
            acc['magnitude'] = acc.apply(magfind, axis = 1) #creates magnitude 
column using prior function, column has magnitudes for every row of every file
            p = acc.loc[:, 'magnitude'].std()#finds std dev for the column and 
appends to a list for graphing
            m = acc.loc[:, 'magnitude'].mean()
            stdlist.append(p)            
      
        elif k == 12 or 20 < k <= last: #data at 12 and beyond hour 20
            hr = intro2 + str(k) + ":"
            tfilter = data[' Time'].str.contains(hr)
            acc = data.loc[tfilter, [' Acc X', ' Acc Y', ' Acc Z']]
            acc['magnitude'] = acc.apply(magfind, axis = 1)
            p = acc.loc[:, 'magnitude'].std()
            m = acc.loc[:, 'magnitude'].mean()
            stdlist.append(p)
        
        else: #in the case that we are dealing with an hour that has no data
            p = 0
            m = 0
            stdlist.append(p) #need this so that the hours with no data still 
get graphed 
        if m > meanmax: # for determining which hour was the most active, and 
appending those magnitudes to a list for histogramming
            meanmax = m
            active = k #most active hour
            for i in acc['magnitude']:
                histlist.append(i) #adding all the magnitudes for histogramming
        
        
        hours.append(k)
        k += 1
    print("mean magnitude", meanmax)
    print("most active hour", active)

    return hours, stdlist, histlist

filterfunction(' 0', ' ', 0, 23)
```

The slow speed stems from the "filterfunction" function. What this program does is read data from over 100 files, and this function specifically sorts the data into a dataframe and analyzes by time (each individual hour) in order to calculate the data in all rows for that hour. I believe that it might be able to be sped up by changing up the way that the data is filtered to search by hour, but am not sure. The reason I have statements to dis-include certain k-values is that there are hours with no data to manipulate, which would mess up the list of standard deviation calculations as well as the plot that this data will father. Any tips or ideas for speeding this up would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion to speed it up a bit is to remove this line since it is not being used anywhere in the program:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

matplotlib is a big library so removing it should improve performance.

Also I think you could get rid of numpy since it is used once only...consider using a tuple

Comment: Thank you! I apologize, matplotlib is vital for another part of the program that I cut out to reduce the size of my already gargantuan post...

Answer (score 0):

I could not able to test because I am on mobile now. However my main idea is not making the code better or leen. I changed the functioning part of the process.

Integrated the 'multiprocessing' library(method) into your code and also calculated the system cpu cores and divide all processes between them.

Multiprocessing library detailed documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import psutil
from datetime import datetime
from multiprocessing import Pool

cores = psutil.cpu_count()

start_time = time.time()#for printing execution time

#function for appending any number of files to a dataframe

def read_data_files(pre, start, end): #reading in the data
    data = pd.DataFrame()#dataframe with all the data from files
    x = start

    while x <= end:
        filename = pre + str(x) + ".csv" #string manipulation
        dpath = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\jacks\\Downloads\\BMEN 207 Project 1 
        Data\\" + filename )

        for y in dpath:
            dpath = dpath.rename(columns = {y: y})
    
        data = data.append(dpath)
        x += 1
       
    return data

data = read_data_files("Data_", 5, 163) #start, end, prefix...

#converting to human time and adding to new column in dataframe
human_time = []

for i in data[' Time']:
    i = int(i)
    j = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(i).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    human_time.append(j)

human_timen = np.array(human_time) #had issues here for some reason, so i 
created another array to replace the time column in the dataframe
data[' Time'] = human_timen

hours = [] #for use as x-axis in plot
stdlist = [] #for use as y-axis in plot
histlist = [] #for storing magnitudes of most active hour

def magfind(row): #separate function to calculate the magnitude of each row in 
each dataframe
    return (row[' Acc X'] ** 2 + row[' Acc Y'] ** 2 + row[' Acc Z'] ** 2) ** .5


def filterfunction(intro1, intro2, first, last): #two different intros to deal 
with the issue of '00:' versus '10:' timestamps
    k = first
    meanmax = 0 
    active = 0

    while k <= last:
        if 0 <= k < 7: #data from hours 0 to 6, none after
            hr = intro1 + str(k) + ':'
            tfilter = data[' Time'].str.contains(hr)
            acc = data.loc[tfilter, [' Acc X', ' Acc Y', ' Acc Z']]
            acc['magnitude'] = acc.apply(magfind, axis = 1) #creates magnitude 
column using prior function, column has magnitudes for every row of every file
            p = acc.loc[:, 'magnitude'].std()#finds std dev for the column and 
appends to a list for graphing
            m = acc.loc[:, 'magnitude'].mean()
            stdlist.append(p)            
      
        elif k == 12 or 20 < k <= last: #data at 12 and beyond hour 20
            hr = intro2 + str(k) + ":"
            tfilter = data[' Time'].str.contains(hr)
            acc = data.loc[tfilter, [' Acc X', ' Acc Y', ' Acc Z']]
            acc['magnitude'] = acc.apply(magfind, axis = 1)
            p = acc.loc[:, 'magnitude'].std()
            m = acc.loc[:, 'magnitude'].mean()
            stdlist.append(p)
        
        else: #in the case that we are dealing with an hour that has no data
            p = 0
            m = 0
            stdlist.append(p) #need this so that the hours with no data still 
get graphed 
        if m > meanmax: # for determining which hour was the most active, and 
appending those magnitudes to a list for histogramming
            meanmax = m
            active = k #most active hour
            for i in acc['magnitude']:
                histlist.append(i) #adding all the magnitudes for histogramming
        
        
        hours.append(k)
        k += 1
    print("mean magnitude", meanmax)
    print("most active hour", active)

    return hours, stdlist, histlist

                            
# Run this with a pool of 5 agents having a chunksize of 3 until finished
agents = cores
chunksize = (len(data) / cores)

with Pool(processes=agents) as pool:
    pool.map(filterfunction, (' 0', ' ', 0, 23))
```

Comment: Just tried that, though it did not make any noticeable improvement. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

don't use `apply`, it's not vectorized. instead, use vectorized operations whenever you can. in this case, instead of doing `df.apply(magfind, 1)`, do:

```
def add_magnitude(df):
    df['magnitude'] = (df[' Acc X'] ** 2 + df[' Acc Y'] ** 2 + df[' Acc Z'] ** 2) ** .5
```

Comment: That halved my runtime. Thank you very much! I can't publicly upvote you because my account is extremely new. Seriously, this will help a lot :)

Comment: on a side note, you might be able to accept it, idk, would be good for other people reading the question.